# Is there a data set which lists common objects and their sizes / measurements / dimensions?

Tags: data-request

I'd like to find a dataset which lists common objects and their physical dimensions:

- apple: 5cm-15cm height, 5cm-10cm width
- car: 1m-2m height, 3m-5m width
- cat: 20cm-30cm height, 30cm-50cm width

Does such a dataset exist?

Comment: I assume a list of works of art with their sizes doesn't fit your goals.

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely, but... I would suggest looking at some complex life simulation games. Probably some of them are open-sourced and have open data with objects inside.

Still, It's too simplified to measure common objects this way.